# Rewrite Programming Phoenix example function using pipes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Programming Phoenix, chapter 3, there is a hardcoded repo example with the following code:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Repo do
  @moduledoc """
  In memory repository.
  """

  def all(Rumbl.User) do
    [%Rumbl.User{id: "1", name: "José", username: "josevalim", password: "elixir"},
     %Rumbl.User{id: "2", name: "Bruce", username: "redrapids", password: "7langs"},
     %Rumbl.User{id: "3", name: "Chris", username: "chrismccord", password: "phx"}]
  end

  def all(_module), do: []

  def get(module, id) do
    Enum.find all(module), fn map -> map.id == id end
  end

  def get_by(module, params) do
    Enum.find all(module), fn map ->
      Enum.all?(params, fn {key, val} -> Map.get(map, key) == val end)
    end
  end
end
```

Using a pipe, I rewrote `get/2` in a way that seems easier to understand:

```
  def get(module, id) do
    all(module)
    |> Enum.find fn map -> map.id == id end
  end
```

Is there a simple way to do the same to `get_by/2`?

Answer (score 3):

My thoughts are that in this case, the clarity would more likely be achieved, not by the pipeline operator itself, but giving descriptive names to the two different functions passed to the different `Enum` functions, instead of using the anonymous function syntax.

```
def get_by(module, params) do
  Enum.find all(module), is_superset_of?(params)
end

defp is_superset_of?(key_value_pairs) do
  fn map -> Enum.all?(key_value_pairs, key_value_pair_in?(map)) end
end

defp key_value_pair_in?(map) do
  fn {key, value} -> Map.get(map, key) == value end
end
```

This is done by taking advantage of the fact that functions can return functions, and close over the values passed in.  This allows us to give a name to a function that represents the previous function that was anonymous (unnamed) and inlined to take advantage of the ability to close over the values needed.

We are now able to sill capture the closed over values, but at the same time increase the expressiveness of what we are trying to accomplish.

All this, assuming that I did interpret the intent of the anonymous functions accurately, as well. ;)

Comment: Thank you Proctor. 
I agree that it makes things easier to understand.
Tiny detail: both `defp`s needed a `do` after the function name and arguments.
Again: thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, was doing it without syntax highlighting, _and_ syntastic running in vim. :O

Answer (score 2):

if you wanted, you could do:

```
def get_by(module, params) do
  module
  |> all()
  |> Enum.find(fn map ->
    Enum.all?(params, fn {key, val} -> Map.get(map, key) == val end)
  end)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I guess my question is more about a way to use pipes to "unentangle" the nested Enum.find, Enum.all? and Map.get :)

Comment: A separate function then, as Proctor said, is the way to go.